# How do I redirect the output and errors from a cronjob to separate files?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a cronjob set every 3 minutes to run a bash script. Now, I wish to separate the output and the errors to two separate files. I did read the answer given in [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file) and tried `*/3 * * * * ./script.sh>>output.log 2>>errors.log` (`>>`, since I'm creating the file in case it doesn't exist), but this seems to redirect the output again to `errors.log`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: may be your o/p is also going to stderr
just do */3 * * * * ./script.sh 2>>errors.log and check if it is redirect the output  as well  erros.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work just fine.

Perhaps your problem is that you are not using absolute paths for the script and the log files?